# Insert string before and after the result of "return"

Tags: javascript, string

I don't know how to be specific on this, but I am trying to insert a string before and after the result of "return" which render one or many div.

It actually does on the global one, but I need another one inside, but it will more clear with an example. Sorry, I'm far from good on this...

My function:

```
var fontsList = '<div class="list">' + Object.keys(families).map(function(familyName) {
    chaine = families[familyName].map(function(variants) {

        return '<div class="all-sub-fonts" style="font-family:'+ variants.postscriptName +';" onclick=\'fontUsed("' + variants.postscriptName + '", this)\'></div>'
    })

    return '<div class="font-box-name" style="font-family:'+ familyName +';" onclick=\'fontUsed("' + familyName + '", this)\'>' + familyName + '<div class="arrow-sub"></div></div>'+ chaine.join('') +'';
}).join('') + '</div>';
```

But now I need to wrap the divs from `class="sub-all-fonts"` into a div

```
 var fontsList = '<div class="list">' + Object.keys(families).map(function(familyName) {
        chaine = families[familyName].map(function(variants) {
// <NEW DIV>
            return '<div class="all-sub-fonts" style="font-family:'+ variants.postscriptName +';" onclick=\'fontUsed("' + variants.postscriptName + '", this)\'><div class="variants-font">' + familyName + ' ' + variants.style + '</div></div>'
        })
// <END OF NEW DIV>

        return '<div class="font-box-name" style="font-family:'+ familyName +';" onclick=\'fontUsed("' + familyName + '", this)\'>' + familyName + '<div class="arrow-sub"></div></div>'+ chaine.join('') +'';
    }).join('') + '</div>';
```

Comment: just start the new `div` before `chaine=...`

Comment: @Edwin I tried with `'<div class="box-sub-fonts">' + chaine = ...` and without "`+`" but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Keep the chaine function and after it wrap the HTML produced by chaine inside a new div. Then append the new div inside your string instead of appending chaine's output:

```
chaine = families[familyName].map(function(variants) {
// <NEW DIV>
            return '<div class="all-sub-fonts" style="font-family:'+ variants.postscriptName +';" onclick=\'fontUsed("' + variants.postscriptName + '", this)\'><div class="variants-font">' + familyName + ' ' + variants.style + '</div></div>'
        })
var htmlString = '<div class="MYNEWDIV">' + chaine.join('') + '</div>';
return '<div class="font-box-name" style="font-family:'+ familyName +';" onclick=\'fontUsed("' + familyName + '", this)\'>' + familyName + '<div class="arrow-sub"></div></div>'+ htmlString;
```

Comment: I'm having a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input" when adding your code, I need to find where it doesn't close

Comment: sorry there is an extra `'` at the end, changing the code

Comment: actually there was an empty string appended at the end, let's try in this way let me know I will paste you the entire code not just the inner function

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you create a variable to store the `begin` and the `end` of the div?

Example:

```
var fontsList = '<div class="list">' + Object.keys(families).map(function(familyName) {
        chaine = families[familyName].map(function(variants) {
        var beginDiv = '<div> class='wrapper'>'
        var endDiv = '</div>'
        var middleDiv = '<div class="all-sub-fonts" style="font-family:'+ variants.postscriptName +';" onclick=\'fontUsed("' + variants.postscriptName + '", this)\'><div class="variants-font">' + familyName + ' ' + variants.style + '</div></div>'
            return beginDiv + middleDiv + endDiv
        })
        return '<div class="font-box-name" style="font-family:'+ familyName +';" onclick=\'fontUsed("' + familyName + '", this)\'>' + familyName + '<div class="arrow-sub"></div></div>'+ chaine.join('') +'';
    }).join('') + '</div>';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your example wrap each div, and in my case I would like to wrap all of those "generated" divs into one div.

Answer (score 0):

Just insert `chaineString = '<div class="box-sub-fonts">' + chaine.join('') + '</div>'` before the second return.

Then change the second return to `... + chaineString + ...`

```
var fontsList = '<div class="list">' + Object.keys(families).map(function(familyName) {
    var chaine = families[familyName].map(function(variants) {
        return '<div class="all-sub-fonts" style="font-family:'+ variants.postscriptName +';" onclick=\'fontUsed("' + variants.postscriptName + '", this)\'></div>'
    });

    var chaineString = '<div class="box-sub-fonts">' + chaine.join('') + '</div>'

    return '<div class="font-box-name" style="font-family:'+ familyName +';" onclick=\'fontUsed("' + familyName + '", this)\'>' + familyName + '<div class="arrow-sub"></div></div>'+ chaineString +'';
}).join('') + '</div>';
```

By doing so, you concatenate the array to a string before returning it as part of your second return, and so you can do more string concatenation with it.

Of course, you could also just add the div to your second return statement

```
return '<div class="font-box-name" style="font-family:'+ familyName +';" onclick=\'fontUsed("' + familyName + '", this)\'>' + familyName + '<div class="arrow-sub"></div></div><div class="box-sub-fonts">'+ chaine.join('') +'</div>';
```